# Function with unconditionally uniformly convergent Fourier series

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Is there a periodic function (seen as a function on the torus $T^k$) such that the associated Fourier family $(c_n e_n)_{n\in \mathbb{Z^k}}$ (where the $(c_n)$ are the usual Fourier coefficients, and $(e_n)$ is the Fourier basis) 
is

- summable in $C(T^k)$ (with the uniform norm) (this is equivalent to : the Fourier series $\sum_n c_n e_n$ is *unconditionnally* uniformly convergent)
- not absolutely summable in $C(T^k)$ (this is equivalent to $\sum_n |c_n|=\infty$)

Note : the example given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3165664/function-with-uniformly-but-non-absolutely-convergent-fourier-series?rq=1) of a function with uniformly convergent but non absolutely convergent Fourier series does not seem to me (but I could be wrong) such that its Fourier series converges unconditionally. (If that's the case, that answers my question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that unconditional convergence of a Fourier series is equivalent to its absolute convergence.

To see this, note that if $T : X \to Y$ is a bounded linear operator and if $\sum_i x_i$ converges unconditionally in $X$, then $\sum_i T x_i$ converges unconditionally in $Y$ (why?!).

Now apply this to $T : C(T^k) \to \Bbb{C}, f \mapsto f(0)$ to see that if $\sum_k c_k e_k$ converges unconditionally, then the series
$$
\sum_k c_k = \sum_k c_k T e_k
$$
converges unconditionally in $\Bbb{C}$. It is well-known that in $\Bbb{C}$, unconditional convergence is equivalent to absolute convergence.